# Self-Organizing maps : is a N*M grid the same as a M*N grid? (with M different from N)

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, self-organizing-maps

Self-Organizing maps : will a N*M grid give the same results as a M*N grid? (with M different from N)?

Answer (score 0):

A nonlinear mapping from continuous feature space (data space) to discrete neuron space (grid) can be performed using SOM. The topology and bounding of the neurons on the grid can affect the performance of mapping and topology preservation but the important thing to consider is the relative position of the winner neurons for the sample vectors (inputs). Hence, without any change in learning factors, MxN and NxM maps won't be significantly different in performance.